# Lists using CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I am learning JavaScript and CSS and got stuck somewhere-

I have three different lists top_menu, submenu3 and submenu4, when I click on item no 3 I want submenu 3 to show up and when I click on item no 4 I want submenu4 to show up and submenu3 should vanish.
My HTML Code is-

```
<ul id="top_menu">
    <li onclick="arrow(1)"><a href="#">item no 1</a>
    </li>
    <li onclick="arrow(2)"><a href="#">item no 2</a> 
    </li>
    <li onclick="arrow(3)"><a href="#">item no 3</a>
    </li>
    <li onclick="arrow(4)"><a href="#">item no 4</a>
    </li>

</ul>
<ul id="submenu1" style="display:none;"></ul>
<ul id="submenu2" style="display:none;"></ul>
<ul id="submenu3" style="display:none;">
    <li><a href="#">A3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">B3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">C3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">D3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">E3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul id="submenu4" style="display:none;">
    <li><a href="#">A4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">B4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">C4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">D4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">E4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and JavaScript implementation for function arrow() is
function arrow(x) {

```
    for (i = 1; i <5; i++) {

        if (i==x) {
            document.getElementById("submenu"+i).style.display = "block";
        }

        else {
         document.getElementById("submenu"+i).style.display = "none";
        }

    }
}
```

Could someone tell where the mistake is?
Thanks!

Comment: Is there any element with the ID `submenu1`?  If not, your loop will fail on the first run and it won't get to your other menus.

Comment: @KennyThompson I have edited the question. Kindly have a look. I have added submenu1 and submenu2

Comment: Your code seems to be working for me... what is the problem?

Comment: @BalintDomokos then why isn't the same code working here  http://jsfiddle.net/kgu/6L35bnL2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for statement should be

```
for (i = 1; i <5; i++)
```

Apart from that it seems to be working for me.

Comment: Yes I have corrected that. Could you please check if this is working? http://jsfiddle.net/kgu/6L35bnL2/

Comment: I used a plain html file and opened in a browser. In jsfiddle it does not work, because the arrow function is defined later than it is used i guess. If you open Inspect element in chrome, you see "arrow is not defined" error message in the console.

Answer (score 0):

A non elegant solution would be to declare your function at the global scope :

```
window.arrow=function(x){
```

`for (i = 1; i <5; i++) {`

```
    if (i==x) {

        document.getElementById("submenu"+i).style.display = "block";
    }

    else {
     document.getElementById("submenu"+i).style.display = "none";
    }

}
```

`}`